# Trouble installing from Remote Disc

Tags: install, filesystem, file-sharing, package-management, remote-disc

My MacBook has no optical drive. I have a Mac installation disc mounted and shared on a local Ubuntu machine and can access it, on the MacBook through the Remote Disc device in Finder.

However, the installation package and all sub-packages, have been stripped of the dot in their file names. Hence it is not recognised as an package.

Why is this and how can I install the software?

Thanks

(To share the disc I used openssh-server on Ubuntu and Macfusion on the Mac.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

1. On the Ubuntu machine, make a ZIP file of the installation package.
2. Copy this file across to the Mac, using your existing sharing setup.
3. Expand it on the Mac and run it.

**Edit**
The actual solution can be found in the comments below: use `sudo mkdir /media/test; sudo mount -t hfsplus /dev/cdrom /media/test` to mount the CD on the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but when I tried this I noticed that the dots were missing on the Ubuntu side too! Could it be that this is some sort of anti-copying technique that prevents the disc from being used for anything other than a regular install?

Comment: I doubt it's an anti-copying technique... more likely Ubuntu isn't reading it correctly.  I found a suggestion [here](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1549169) to mount the CDROM on Ubuntu using (eg) `sudo mkdir /media/test; sudo mount -t hfsplus /dev/cdrom /media/test` -- is that any help?

Comment: Yes, manually mounting and specifying the filesystem type as per your comment, worked for me. Many thanks.